# Will all be able to see after resurrection?

Tags: quran, tafseer

There are verses like 50:20-23 (verse 22 in particular) which state that **EVERY** (arabic word used is kul) soul will witness the judgement of Allah SWT being sentenced upon him/her with sharp eyes and clear perception. However, there are verses like 17:72, 97 and 20:124-127 which unequivocally state that there will be sinners being raised blind. If every soul is to see their recorded deeds, then how can we explain the latter verses? If there will be those raised blind, then doesn't this negate the use of "every"? I need help refuting this supposed contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

There are two main ways of understanding the verses of people being "blind" on the Day of Judgement.

First, I will quote a translation of the verse in the Quran:

> And whoever Allah guides - he is the [rightly] guided; and whoever He sends astray - you will never find for them protectors besides Him, **and We will gather them on the Day of Resurrection [fallen] on their faces - blind, dumb and deaf.** Their refuge is Hell; every time it subsides We increase them in blazing fire. (17:97)

Ibn Al-Jawzi mentions in his tafsir the two overall possible meanings of "being gathered blind" ([relevant part in Arabic](https://tafsir.app/zad-almaseer/17/97)).

The first is that they are blind from good things, but they can still see the judgement and other things. Different opinions in this line of thought:

- Blind means they are not able to see anything that pleases them, dumb means they are not able to make any sound argument, and deaf means they are not able to hear anything that pleases them. This is an opinion attributed to Ibn Abbas (RA), and it is a commonly held one.
- Similarly, blind can mean they cannot see the rewards prepared for the good people, dumb can mean they cannot speak to Allah, and deaf can mean they cannot hear the praise given to the good people.

The second possible meaning is that they are blind in a portion of the Aakhirah. There are different opinions regarding what portion:

- They are made blind, deaf, and dumb in Hell after Allah tells them, "Remain despised therein and do not speak" (23:108)
- They are made to see and hear while Allah gives them their book and His Judgement but otherwise they are blind.
- They are made blind when they are gathered towards Hell even though they were raised from death seeing.

In my opinion, the first opinion that is attributed to Ibn Abbas (RA) makes the most sense. They are probably brought to life on Judgement Day unable to see any good things.

Comment: What about 20:124-127? The verses relate a conversation between Allah SWT and a wrongdoer. Here the latter will say that he was made to see in this life but Allah SWT will raise him blind.

Comment: The verses are explicit that it's talking about physical blindness

Comment: @Afiq Ibn Kathir explains those verses as meaning they are blind to everything except Hell. That's why since the person could not see anything around him, he asks Allah what he asks in those verses. This is the same as what I gave in my answer.

Comment: @Afiq Not necessarily. It would mean that the Kafir was able to see plenty excuses in life but is now unable to find any. Even 50:22 is not necessarily literally about physical sight. If all of these verses are taken to mean physical and absolute eye-sight then the explanation about different states in different periods applies.

Answer (score 1):

IMO @TheZ has given a comprehensive answer. I will just add a little to it.

Expressions may have multiple meanings and they may be used in the Quran sometimes in their literal meaning and sometimes in a metaphorical meaning and sometimes there may be implied clauses which are omitted from the text.

Take the example of this verse:

> #### ومن كان في هذه أعمى فهو في الآخرة أعمى وأضل سبيلا
>
> And whoever is blind in this [life] will be blind in the Hereafter and more astray in way.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 17:72](http://quran.com/17/72)</sup>

What does this verse 'explicitly' say? If you insist on a literal, absolute and physical interpretation of "blind" then it means that every disabled person is going to be disabled and astray in the afterlife. Why would Allah do that to an innocent and already suffering person? Rather blind here is used in a specific meaning and there is something that is implied in the sentence but is not explicitly present in the text.

Similarly, in the verses you have cited *perception* and *blind* are not meant in the meaning that you are taking. And it is not contradictory for a person to be simultaneously blind in one sense and perceiving in another, nor in being blind at one stage of the afterlife and perceptive in another.

There is no contradiction rather it is a trick of persuasion that is used to misguide gullible people by ignoring how the the recipients of the Quran understood it, suggesting your own meaning to the words and then pointing out the internal inconsistencies that arise from your own misinterpretation.